# Why can't I read parameters that I received in POST?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, jsp

I am passing parameters in the `JSP` file by `POST` method. However, the `ID value` is obtained, but the `Password value` is not readable.

**sendparameter.jsp**

```
<div class="intro">
    <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="logo">test</div>
            <h4>test</h4>
            <form name="frm" action="receive.jsp" method="POST" >
            <div class="form-line">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="admin_id" id="admin_id" onkeyup="enterkey()">
            </div>
            <div class="form-line">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="admin_password" id="admin_password" onkeyup="enterkey()" >
            </div>
            <div class="btn-wrap">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="login" onClick="loginbutton()">login</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            <div class="copyright">
                2019
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**receive.jsp**

```
<%
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

String name = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("admin_id");
String pass = (String)request.getParameter("admin_password");

System.out.println("admin_id :" + name); // get name
System.out.println("admin_password :" + pass); // It's null
%>
...
<script>
    var myVar = '<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("admin_password") %>';
    alert(myVar); // It also null
</script>
```

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("admin_password"); // is not work
```

How can you solve this problem? Thanks you in advance

Comment: what does `loginbutton()` function do ?

Comment: Hi @Swati Compare the ID and password with the DB, and if correct, save the ID value and move on to the next screen.

Comment: @Swati Look at my question. This is another page with a different file name.

Comment: HI @YoManTaMero I don't save my password in a session. Can't you get a value without saving it to a session? Why is the getparameter not applicable?

Comment: Can you check what parameters are passed using `request.getParameterNames()`?

Comment: `request.getParameterNames()` is `java.util.Collections$3@1b28e2a4`

Comment: I meant the contents, not the output of `toString()` ;-)

Comment: I tried many things, but I didn't try to get it from the session. My question shows that all the functions that come with the password have been tried. But I couldn't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because I was controlling URi using a page controller file. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your form is not getting submitted. 
Admin Id your are getting from Session not from jsp form submission.

Use this :-

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="login" onClick="loginbutton()">login</button>
```

Instead of

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="login" onClick="loginbutton()">login</button>
```

As type="submit", submits all form values to a form-handler.